# ecmascript regexp to find/replace Chrome homepage

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

Our company is changing to Chrome as a default internet browser. Unfortunately part of our corporate policy is to have the homepage set to our intranet URL. I have found that the settings for Chrome's homepage is in `Local Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\default\Preferences` and the line that contains the homepage is:

`"startup_urls": [ "http://www.fave1.com", "http://www.fave2.com"],`

However as many of our users have already set their own homepages, I cannot do a simple search and replace of `"startup_urls": [ "http://www.google.com"],` with our own URL.

My regex skills are seriously rusty, can someone spare the time to show me how to match this entire line regardless of the URL, so that I can then replace it with our own URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search expression:

```
"startup_urls": \[([^\]]*)\]
```

Replace expression:

```
"startup_urls": ["http://intranet", $1]
```

I hope my employer doesn't do this!  Seriously annoying, my chrome instance reopens whatever was open when it closed (my point is it does what I want, not what my employer wants).

Comment: If this is a policy that runs repeatedly, it will keep inserting `"http://intranet"` at the start of the startup_urls list. There will be an additional tab every time it runs.  If you leave out `, $1` then it will delete any home pages your employee had set themselves. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this would be something Google would really support; therefore, it would be subject to change with an update without warning, etc. I would recommend looking at enforcing this as a policy rather than changing the settings on the machines like this.

[Documentation for Administrators](http://www.chromium.org/administrators) - gives a good overview on how to set Machine-level policies which will be in place for Chrome regardless of users signing into Chrome.

If you're using Google Apps, you can also look into enforcing policies via the Admin console as per [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2657289). Note, this will only apply to browser sessions where the user has logged into Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check that out. I'd still be interested to know how to regex the file though as it's been bugging me all day.